# Can't Install Visual Studio Code with rpm

Tags: fedora, terminal, rpm, visual-studio-code

I am using Fedora 33 with XCFE Desktop. I can't use this command:

`rpm -i https://update.code.visualstudio.com/latest/linux-rpm-arm64/stable`

It only makes a new blank that does nothing and I exited with `^C`. How do I do this corrextly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By following the published instructions rather than inventing your own.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

From those instructions...

**RHEL, Fedora, and CentOS based distributions**

We currently ship the stable 64-bit VS Code in a yum repository, the following script will install the key and repository:

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "[code]\nname=Visual Studio Code\nbaseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/vscode.repo'
```

Then update the package cache and install the package using dnf (Fedora 22 and above):

```
dnf check-update
sudo dnf install code
```

Or on older versions using yum:

```
yum check-update
sudo yum install code
```

Due to the manual signing process and the system we use to publish, the yum repo may lag behind and not get the latest version of VS Code immediately.